# JMeter - JDBC use variable in update statement

Tags: jdbc, jmeter

I would like to delete entry in database by value stored in variable, for some reason this do not work. I tried multiple approaches to no success.

Variable displayed in debug sampler: [image]

JDBC Request [image]

Variable is not translated to corresponding value.
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can normally use [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) in JDBC statements and they're "translated" into their respective values assuming that the variable exists.

Demo:

[image]

You need to know something important about JMeter Variables: they're [local for the thread](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thread-local_storage) (virtual user), if you create variable somewhere - it will be accessible only for the user who created this variable, other users won't have access to it.

If you create a variable by other thread or in another Thread Group - you will either need to convert it into a JMeter Property or use [Inter-Thread Communication Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/InterThreadCommunication/) in order to be able to access it from other threads. See [Using JMeter Variables With Multiple Thread Groups](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-variables) article for more details.

Comment: Thank you, the problem was indeed passing variable between threads. I found this article to be a bit more useful https://www.perfmatrix.com/jmeter-passing-variable-value-to-another-thread-group/ though.